# How to create 2D array type column in pyspark using split() function?

Tags: arrays, loops, pyspark, multidimensional-array, rdd

I am currently working with df containing an array column with values, such that each element in the array is a line containing field value.

eg:

| file_name | line_array |
| --- | --- |
| file 1 | [l1,l2,l3] |
| file 2 | [l1,l2,l3] |

and "l1" value will be like: "1 100 0 0 New". The value "[1,100,0,0, New]" needs to be extracted from the line string, which is separated by a single space.

After transformation:

| file_name | line_array |
| --- | --- |
| file 1 | [[1,100,0,0,New],[values of l2],[values of l3]] |
| file 2 | [[v1],[v2],[v3]] |

how can we derive it?

I tried using the map function but I don't know how to iterate the array value or use the split function in this case
and genuinely have no idea about iterations in pyspark.

Any solutions as well as reading suggestions for better understanding are much appreciated.

P.S: the array might contain null values as well

Comment: What are l1, l2 & l3 mapped to? Are they columns in other dataframe or lines in some files?

Comment: l1,l2,l3 of first row are lines in the file 1. I used split to separate the lines with \n. That generated me an array. And now I would like to apply split to the lines in the array again with \s as delimiter.